# @Viewchild Angular 5, 6 - ElementRef

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, viewchild, elementref

I have referenced a control with ElementRef of Angular and for this I use this code:

HTML :

```
<button #btnSaveGeneralData...
```

Typescript :

```
@ViewChild ('btnSaveGeneralData') btnSaveGeneralData: ElementRef;
```

I need to reference to be able to reach the click () event, with javascript I have solved it:

```
let buttonDG: any = document.getElementsByName ('btnGaveDG') [0];
buttonDG.click ();
```

but doing so with ElementRef does not work, I get the error "... nativeElement undefined":

```
this.btnSaveGeneralData.nativeElement.click ();
```

I could do it with javascript but it's not the idea. Any suggestions, in which I can be wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine.

Maybe your HTML isn't initialized yet, so the `ElementRef` would be `undefined.`
Or you have a spelling error.

[Functioning Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6yh1r)

Comment: I have updated the question. I already did it that way, but I always get an error: "... nativeElement undefined" and if correctly instance "this.btnSaveGeneralData".

Comment: When exactly do you call `this.btnSaveGeneralData.nativeElement.click()` in your component?

Comment: @Flix Broken link. Please update if there is one which is correct.

Comment: @RupamDatta whoops, I edited the link to a functioning Stackblitz.